# Quickly convert single file class to folder-class

Tags: oop, class, function, matlab, code-generation

I have several classes in one single file each. Is there a quick way to convert them to @-folder classes? It's a pain to transfer all single functions to separate function files once by once.

Comment: By folder-class, I presume you mean one with an old-style constructor.

Comment: Yes, they are officially called @-folders, see here: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brfynrp-1.html#brfynrp-2

Comment: I'm thinking more of the pre-R2008a syntax: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/releases/R2007b/techdoc/matlab_prog/f6-48272.html

Comment: okay that's not what I meant :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need that? I was thinking about doing the opposite.

Comment: Why? I have a big class with some big functions and I think it's more understable when you split them into several function-m-files :) Okay I know, concerning OOP I should probably split the class, but that's not an option. I just wanna try to make it as readable as possible.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it helps you, but you might as well put them as functions after the classdef. They will behave like private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to move the existing methods from the `classdef` file: you can just move it to the @-folder and add new methods as separate M-files. Note that methods defined as M-files are always public, unless they're in the `private` subdirectory.

Look at the `timeseries` class as an example of a class defined using a `classdef` file and an @-folder. Should be in `$matlabroot\toolbox\matlab\timeseries\@timeseries`.

Comment: But what about that file that contains *classdef*, how is it going to be treated?

Comment: I know that, but what about the already existing methods? They won't be touched by this :(

Comment: I would just move the biggest methods by hand, rather than moving them all. The classdef file ensures that you have one coherent definition of the class and I would try to avoid breaking that up as much as possible.

Comment: @Andrey, the classdef file is treated the same as if it were in a normal directory on the path. Look at `timeseries` as an example.